# SQL select data from two tables and sort by points

Tags: sql

I have a database table with friends

```
Table `friends`
friend1 | friend2
--------+--------
3       | 4
4       | 1
```

The way I insert friend pairs into the table is by requester to sender, meaning you can be “friend1” in half of the pairs and “friend2” in the other half.

Then I have another table where details about people are, like name, surname, points. There’s an ID that is unique to all people and it is used both in “people” table and “friends” table to identify them (so friend1 = some id, friend2 = some id)

```
Table `people`
idk | name | surname | points
----+------+---------+-------
  1 | John | Doe     |     12
  2 | John | Doe     |     15
  3 | John | Doe     |      5
  4 | John | Doe     |     26
```

Now I want to select all your friends (remember in some pairs you’re “friend1” in others “friend2”) and list all those friends sorted by points from “people” database.

Any idea on How to do it? As one SQL or in PHP.

Result I want:

You are “ID:4”
Friends sorted by points:

```
ID |  points
---+--------
 1 |   12
 3 |    5
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so your question makes sense to other people.

Comment: Noproblemo. I’ll Edit it.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do a `join` like this:

```
select p.*
from friends f join
     people p
     on ( (p.person_id = f.friend1 and f.friend2 = @x) or
          (p.person_id = f.friend2 and f.friend1 = @x)
        )
order by p.points desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just select all table from your `friends table` where the ID of the person appears.

Something like.. :

```
SELECT *
FROM friends f, person p1, person p2
WHERE f.friend1 = p1.id
AND f.friend2 = p2.id
AND (p1.id = HERE YOUR USER ID OR p2.id = HERE YOUR USER ID)
```

In Php you will need to filter the selected person out of the array, and you get all the informations about his friends.